# How to prepare a latex file to ready for flex printing?

Tags: printing

Hello TeX user's i want to know how can we prepare a LaTeX file for flex printing, i heard from someone for flex printing only `.tif` format is supported, but when we build a LaTeX file is generated output as `.pdf`, so if we want to go for flex printing how one can prepare a file for flex printing in LaTeX. Thanking you in advance for your comments.

Comment: Use post-processing. A tool like ImageMagick does support this conversion.

Comment: Will it maintain the same quality like LaTeX produce after conversion@TeXnician?

Comment: No, but it is sufficient if you choose the right options. Remember that you want to convert vector graphics into raster graphics.